# How to get Dynamically Created User Control to show?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control called home that has the location already set. When I dynamically create it below I don't see it. I've tried setting the property to visable using the show and bring to front method but nothing. What am I missing?

> ```
> namespace TipManager {
>      static class Program
>      {
>          /// <summary>
>          /// The main entry point for the application.
>          /// </summary>
>          [STAThread]
>          static void Main()
>          {
>              Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>              Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>              form = new Form1();
>              Application.Run(form);
>
>              TipManagerModel tipManager = new TipManagerModel();
>              TipManagerServices services = new TipManagerServices(tipManager);
>
>              Home homeView = new Home();
>              HomePresenter homePresenter = new HomePresenter(homeView, tipManager, services);
>
>              form.Controls.Add(homeView);
>              homeView.BringToFront();
>          }
>          static Form1 form;
>      } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is being called before adding the control, move `Application.Run(form);` to the end of the function. On a side note, I would highly recommend doing this in the form constructor after `InitializeComponents();` rather than doing it here.

Comment: I feel bad for missing this. All this autogenerated code gets the best of me sometimes. Thank, it's working perfectly. May I ask, why do you suggest I move it to the form constructor? I'm implementing the MVP design pattern and the few examples I've looked at tend to link everything together in this file. Thanks again!

Comment: In fact, `InitializeComponents` is a functions then does what you are doing, but for the components you add using the form design and it gets called in the constructor. So, in my opinion, that would be the best place to put the manually created components. Also, I like to avoid modifying auto generated code since it can cause trouble if you are not taking care while modifying.